# Undefined Length - Pug/Express/MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, pug

The following code keeps generating a `TypeError` message informing me that the `length is undefined`. The problem is rather frustrating as I've used the same route else where within my project and it worked perfectly fine.

### users.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('unable to connect');
    } else {

        collection = db.collection('users');
        collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else if (result.length) {
                res.render('users', {
                    "users": result
                });
            } else {
                res.send('No documents found')
            };
            db.close()
        });
      }
   });
});
```

### users.pug

The error messages points to line 11 (`each user, i in users`) of the below code

```
extends layout.pug

block content

h3 #{title}

ul
    li
        a(href="users/add") Add New user
ul
    each user, i in users <--- Error occurs here
        li
            p #{users._id}
        li
            p #{users.name}
        li
            p #{users.email}
        li
            p #{users.username}
        li
            p #{users.password}
```

Any ideas to help remedy my situation would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance :)

**UPDATE:**
Problem has been solved, turns out I had two `router.get('/')` routes, so if you come across this issue double check you don't have two of the same route

Answer (score 0):

This basically means that `result` is undefined. What happens when you log `result`?

I remember fixing similar stuff by using JSON.stringify() to send data from the server, and JSON.parse() the data client-side. Can you try this, log `result` and give me your results ? :)

Comment: I can't seem to console log it, nor view the value with Node inspector. I may be doing something wrong but it doesn't seem like the route even gets a change to run before the error occurs. Is it an issue with the pug file? I pretty much copy pasted the route and template from another section of my project where it worked fine.

My JS knowledge isn't the best but I'll look into the JSON method you suggested

Comment: When you say `I can't seem to console log it`, what does it mean exactly ? What's the result? If there is an error, what is it ?

Comment: As in any of the console.logs() I put within the route never get a chance to run as the TypeError occurs and kill the server. I can't even seem to trigger a break point with node inspector either.

Comment: If so, the code you are giving us is useless, since it is not causing this issue. Try logging everything until you find the breaking point and what causes it exactly (the error occuring in your .pug file is just a consequence of another error IMO), and give us something to work with!

Comment: I worked it out and boy do I feel silly, it turns out I had 2 GET routes for the same page. Next time I'll triple check everything before asking the community. Anyway thanks for your time and help

Comment: It's fine, we all missed obvious mistakes at one point! Glad to hear you've solved this